# What does libnice do?

Tags: javascript, c, webrtc

I am trying to use erizo to create a media server, erizo uses libnice. When I create a web rtc connection from a browser, what stun server should I use?

stun.l.google.com ?

or

libnice is already a stun server, I should use my own server's IP as stun server's address?

Answer (score 0):

I am not realy sure but in ICE(RFC 5245) is writen that ICE use STUN & TURN so i thing that it is reason why libnice need some STUN server.

libnice is not STUN server but client(agent), libnice search for transaction address colection and try connect using some of this address to another device